# Updating a list item in SharePoint Online without incrementing the version

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate, sharepoint-api

I'm working on a project with Sharepoint Online and PowerAutomate, and I have a small issue that I would like to share with you, in order to find solutions or workarounds.

I have a PowerAutomate flow, which is run by a technical user (service account).
This flow is triggered by an API call, with some parameters as : requestor user id (which is an existing user in the tenant of course), site id, list it, list item id.
The flow retrieve a specific document in a document library (according to parameters passed through the API call) and, at the end of the flow, I would like to publish a major version of this document (check-out + check-in).
This is working properly, but there is an issue : as the flow is run as a technical user, **when the major version is published, the "Modified by" field is set to the name of the technical user, and not the name of the user which called the API.**

I saw that it seems possible to make a call with the specific parameter

```
"bNewDocumentUpdate": true
```

to make an update without incrementing the version.

So, at the end of the flow I make the call as follow :

```
{
    "formValues": [  {
      "FieldName": "Editor",
      "FieldValue": "[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|my.user@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com'}]"
        }
    ],
    "bNewDocumentUpdate": true
}
```

I make the following observations :

1. If I make this call directly after the major version publishing, the "Modified by" field is well updated with my business user name, but the version is incremented : *v2.0 --> call to update editor --> v2.1*   which is not satisfactory for my use case
2. If I make the same call on a minor version, the "Modified by" field is well updated with my business user name, and the version is not incremented : *v2.4 --> call to upddate editor --> v2.4 as well*

So, my questions are :

1. How do you explain the fact that the same call produce two different behaviours depending of the version number when I make the call, and do you know a workaround to avoid incrementing the version number ?
2. Do you have an other idea to troubleshoot this issue? DO you know if there is another way to publish a major version on behalf my business user, despite the fact that the PowerAutomate flow is run as a technical user

Many thanks for your help, and have a great day.